# The world's largest companies

Tags: reference-request, data-request, industrial-organisation

There are several criteria (or key figures) to list the world's "largest" companies, giving quite different lists:

- [revenue](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue) (in \$)
- profit (in \$)
- assets (in \$)
- [market capitalization](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Market_capitalization) (in \$)
- number of employees

For **any** company the following key figure or [financial ratio](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Financial_ratio) makes sense (for investors mainly), depending on the exact definitions of "profit" and "revenue":

- [profit margin](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Profit_margin) = profit / revenue

For [public companies](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Public_company) the following key figures / criteria / financial ratios make sense, too:

- wage per employee = average wage (in \$) = total wages / number of employees
- median wage (in \$)
- minimal/maximal wage (in \$)
- revenue per employee (in \$)
- profit per employee (in \$)
- assets per employee (in \$)
- market capitalization per employee (in \$)

> **Where do I find concise overviews and comparisons of such numbers for large companies like [these](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue) (sorted by revenue)** (yellow = state-owned enterprise):

[image]

*<sub>[Please tell me better tags for this question than those I have used!]</sub>*

Comment: It may help potential answerers if you could include the purpose for the use of the data. Most of the figures you asked for can be computed/tabulated if you have an access to a [Bloomberg Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloomberg_Terminal) or [Compustat database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compustat).

Comment: @HerrK.Thanks for your hint. What kind of purpose is "just want to know"? Including if these questions are *asked* by others (revenue/profit/assets per employee as key figures) and *answered* by the databases you mention: median/min/max wage?

Comment: OK, can you describe the real-world problem that you are trying to solve? (as per the help centre's guidance: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.")

Comment: The real world problem is: To identify those large companies with a bad ratio of profit (margin) to expenses for environmental protection and other [SDGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustainable_Development_Goals).